# Some methods are not present while updating from vaadin7 to vaadin8

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin8

Update from vaadin 7.7.6 to vaadin 8

I am trying to upgrade my project from java8 to java11 and from vaadin7 to vaadin8. I am not able to find the alternatives for few vaadin methods in vaadin 8. The methods are related to the below classes.

```
import org.vaadin.peter.contextmenu.ContextMenu;
import org.vaadin.peter.contextmenu.ContextMenu.ContextMenuItem;
import org.vaadin.peter.contextmenu.ContextMenu.ContextMenuItemClickEvent;
import org.vaadin.peter.contextmenu.ContextMenu.ContextMenuItemClickListener;
import com.avaya.ept.dr.ra.view.contexmenu.ContextMenuContent;
```

In my existing code I have below methods :

```
final ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
if (someConditionHere) {
   contextMenu.addItem("some caption here... ");
}else {
   ContextMenuItem item;
   item = contextMenu.addItem("someString");
   item.setData(someObject);
   item.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Since in vaadin8 **ContextMenuItem** is not present so What could be the alternative for the above block of code.

My second question is in the below code we are using **ComboBoxMultiSelect** which has a method `combo.addItem(string)` but in vaadin8 what could be the replacement for this method ?

```
AbstractField abstractField = RaComponentFactory.getFactory().createComponent(NAME, "LUT_"
                        + dim.getName()+ "_" + rowCreationCounter, ComboBoxMultiSelect.class);
        final com.avaya.ept.dr.ra.view.components.ComboBoxMultiSelect combo = (ComboBoxMultiSelect)abstractField;
combo.addItem(string);
```

My third question is in the interface `public interface Component extends ClientConnector, Sizeable, Serializable` we are having a method `void setReadOnly(boolean var1);` which is not present in vaadin8 so what could be the alternative for this method ?

Please provide some suggestions here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is too wide question to answer in StackOverflow, but watch this training video to get started https://vaadin.com/learn/training/vaadin-7-to-8

Comment: Why do you want to upgrade to an obsolete version? For several reasons, it would be advisable to switch to version 14 or rather to 23 or to 24 right away. But you probably have a good reason for this choice anyway.
If I'm right the context menu in your vaadin7 project was come from an addon, so you have to find the right replacement for vaadin 8. I would make a try with this: https://vaadin.com/directory/component/vaadin-contextmenu
AFAIK, V7 has no built-in multi select Combobox, so it seems it's also an addon. Btw in V8 you should refresh all the items with setItems() or setDataProvider().